# Использование одной базы для авторизации двух сайтов на django

Tags: python, django, cookie

есть 2 сайта на разных виртуалках site1.my.ru, site2.my.ru
Я сделал роут для базы данных, чтобы модели приложения auth и contenttype второй сайт использовал из базы   первого.
Сделал это для того, чтобы пользователь мог авторизоваться на обоих сайтах общим логопасом и имел сходные права.
Проблема в том, что когда пользователь лоигинится на первом сайте, его выкидывает со второго и наоборот.
В settings.py у меня указан параметр `session_cookie_domain = '.my.ru'`, я думал это что то вроде wildcard для куков, но в итоге ничего не получилось.
Как сделать чтобы пользователя не выкидывало с одного сайта, когда он заходит на другой?

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать, называется SSO https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0 и делается другими средствами.

Comment: @gbg спасибо за наводку, меня сбило с толку, что в документации django multiple database, на примере как раз показывается база с учётками

Comment: Вот бы ещё кто объяснил почему разлогинивает и как сделать, чтобы хотя бы не разлогинивало.

Comment: Посмотрите функцию authenticate скорее всего там происходит привязка к домену. А так используйте https://github.com/django-cas-ng/django-cas-ng для мультидоменной авторизации